# How to debug "incorrect checksum for freed object" error in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I'm currently testing my application using a Right-To-Left language setting in Xcode and everytime I start the application I'm getting the error below.

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1013819e8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

With a Left-To-Right setting the app works fine.
How would I debug this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Turn on zombies in your target's build scheme and it will tell you where you're attempting to change this after it was freed. Also, the static analyzer ("Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu) is exceptionally good at finding these situations.

Comment: Ha! Found the issue - [NSTableView drawGridInClipRect:].. I removed the grid line from the table view and everything is working fine. Weird.